# IIS7 SSL certificate caching

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

I changed certificate in IIS 7, changed bindings on websites, everything OK. But when I'm trying to set my old certificate (and I'm changed bindings too), I still get new certificate instead of old. I deleted cache, certificates from browser, opened from another machines, but there is no effect. When I open website from machine, where is it runned, I can see, that there is my old certificate, so IIS7 changed certificate... But where the certificate can be cached?
P.S. To prevent misunderstanding - I want to return to my OLD certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading [ssltools manager](http://www.ssltools.com/manager) to verify that certificate was indeed deleted. If it has, try restarting the site or even the server.

Comment: I restarted sites and server too. Does firewall can cache sertificate? (There is a firewall over local network that filtering incoming requests)

Comment: You can try viewing the site from the same server as the ssl cert is installed so that you can bypass any appliance that might be caching the site